# CSS transformation change during transition causes current state to get lost and jumps to the beginning (Chrome bug)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transforms

Tested in Google Chrome 73 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Also tested in latest stable Mozilla, Opera and Safari.

Looks like it is a bug of Chrome only. Hope there is a workaround until the Chrome team fix the bug.

## Demo

I have created [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLRWjL) to show the problem.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

const cssTransition = 2500;
const states = [
  ['INITIAL', 'translate(0)', cssTransition / 2],
  ['A', 'translate(0, 100px)', cssTransition + 500],
  ['B', 'translate(100px, 100px)', cssTransition / 2],
];

let cursor = 0;

const animate = () => {
  cursor = (cursor + 1) % states.length;
  const [name, value, delay] = states[cursor];
  setTimeout(() => {
    div.innerText = name;
    div.style.transform = value;
    animate();
  }, delay);
};

animate();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transition: 2.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div>INITIAL</div>
```

## Task

Animate element via JavaScript to change its position on the screen using CSS3 transform property.

**Conditions:**

1. Element has fixed transition time (defined in CSS file).
2. At any time of animation JavaScript may set new position of element might i.e. change will happen before existing animation finished.
3. New position of element is not known in advance => i.e. list of CSS classes is not an option here.

**The problem is** - transition is not smooth because new animation jumps from initial position of previous animation instead of smooth transition from current location.

## Actual behavior

When CSS transform property of an element is changed during transition (i.e. before current animation finished) the next animation starts from the initial state of previous animation.

[image: wrong, jumpy css transition]

- **steps 1-5** is first animation (transition between INITIAL and A states).
- **steps 6-10** is second animation (transition between INITIAL and B states).
- **step 3** is where first animation got interrupted because final transform property changed i.e. second animation starts here.

As you can see, animation jumps to INITIAL state which is wrong (undesired). Position at step 6 should be near step 3.

## Expected behavior

CSS transform property change should reset internal animation timer to 0 (so, new animation will last as defined in transition property) but keep current transform state as initial state for the next animation.

[image: proper, expected css transition]

- **steps 1-5** is first animation (transition between INITIAL and A states).
- **steps 6-10** is second animation (transition between intermediate "INITIAL to A" and B states).
- **step 3** is where first animation got interrupted because final transform property changed i.e. second animation starts here.

As you can see, new animation starts exactly where it is expected - from step 3 and nicely move element to the new position.

Thanks for reading. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Testing right now, it actually works sometimes even though it's not perfectly smooth (simply refresh your pen multiple times). Seems like a weird bug.

Comment: Check out my [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGgOBO), the behavior on the right is basically what you want to achieve but with animation interruptions (which can't be achieved through css animations) right ?

Comment: @Jake yes, something like that. Btw, I see you set "linear" type of transition which works almost OK. But if you set "transition: transform 2.5s ease;" it will jump to the very initial state.

Comment: It still happened in 2020 :(. A workaround is using `left` / `top` instead of `translate`

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure why it happens but a solution would be to manually set the transitioned property (here `transform`) to its currently computed value, right before changing to the new desired one.

```
div.style.transform = getComputedStyle(div).transform;
// Cause a reflow to force the browser to apply the set transform
div.innerWidth;
div.style.transform = value;
```

Here is a [fork of your pen](https://codepen.io/bali_balo/pen/6f96551c6e61ec087aa8b7911e34614a) including the fix.

`getComputedStyle` is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle) so you don't need to worry about a polyfill unless you want to support IE < 9